# If the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are $\hat{f} \in \ell_{2}$ then $f \in L_2$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Given a function $f$ with Fourier coefficients  $\hat{f} \in \ell_{2}$, is $f \in L_{2}$?

Comment: Please show what you have done. The answer is YES, but we have to know what you already know about Fourier series.

Comment: Do you know Parseval's identity ?

Comment: Yes, I know all about it. I tried to use Parseval but in order to use it I need to know that the function is already in $L_2$ which I don't know. The proof of the other direction is easy (If $f\in L_2$ then $\hat{f}\in l_2$ using Parseval) but I'm wondering how to proof this direction. I thought about using the generalized pythagorean theorem.